# How do I avoid IFTTT changing file names as part of a Gmail recipe (using FileUrl)?

Tags: if-this-then-that

I have a recipe to send files from a dropbox folder to my @kinde email address to be converted and delivered to my device. The problem is... the filename ends up "mangled". Say I copy a file, "**Pacific Express.pdf**", into the folder. It ends up on my kindle as "**pacific20express**".

File naming is very important on the Kindle. It takes the name of the file without the extension as the display-name for the book on the device. It cannot be renamed on the device or the online content manager. This makes for a very ugly library and effectively ruins the recipe.

I suspect that IFTTT is downcasing and URL-encoding the `FileUrl` component (of the recipe) and that Kindle is stripping the `%` from the URL-encoded space, `%20`.

I don't know if this can be fixed or worked-around. When I manually attach/email these files to my @kindle email address it shows up with the casing/punctuation preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Previously, I have used wappwolf (an alternative app) to solve this, but it closed down in the last couple of days.
https://twitter.com/WAPPWOLF/status/983629320697491457

I discovered a new solution today, using "Microsoft Flow" (which I had never heard of before). https://flow.microsoft.com

When I automate a Dropbox to email/Google Drive using its service, the 
Filename and extension are retained. Give that a go. That might work for you until IFTTT adjust their protocol.